# Why does `Bits` depend on `Num`?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I've been coding my own bit-vectors (represented as strict tuples over `Word64` values) as an exercise in time and space optimizations and wanted to define instances of the `Bits` typeclass for them, but then I noticed that the class declaration for `Bits` is defined as follows:

```
class Num a => Bits a
```

To workaround this, I'm defining a fake `Num` instance as well, made up mostly of `error`-valued functions as a hack, but this doesn't feel right...

What was the rationale of *depending* on the `Num` type-class for bit-wise operations? Wouldn't it make more sense to be able to have `Bits` instances independen from having to declare a `Num` instance as well?

Comment: You could define a meaningful `Num` instance for your bit-vectors by treating them as integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Bits` depends on `Num`, because `Num` provides numeric literals and negation, which are used in the default methods for `Bits`, like so:

```
bit :: Int -> a
bit i               = 1 `shiftL` i

testBit           :: a -> Int -> Bool    
x `testBit` i       = (x .&. bit i) /= 0
```

If there were no default methods, you could imagine getting away without the `Num` constraint.

Comment: Some people actually say, that this is a design-failure. But I fully understand this.

Comment: In your example using `shift :: a -> Int -> a`, I don't see any of `Num`'s operations on `a` being used?

Comment: Actually, you're right, @hvr!  Though other things like `bit` do. Fixed.

Comment: Ok, I've looked at the default implementations, and so far I've only seen the requirement on the `Eq` operation, and being able to instantiate a `0`-vector and a primitive `1`-vector... but I see no use of `Num`'s negation operation... yet -- but this still seems a bit of overkill to me... :-)

Comment: Am I right, that the requirement of `Num` could be avoided altogether if the integer literals feature of the `Num` was split into an `IsIntegral` typeclass (similiar to the `IsString` facility)?

Comment: @hvr And we could also split the other functions into `Mulable`, `Negable`, `Sumable`, etc. :)

Comment: @FUZxxl: what's the difference between `Addable` and `Sumable`? :)

Comment: @hvr fixed. IIRC there was also a recent post on the Haskell Planet about "Why Typeclasses should have only one function".

Comment: The design failure is that integer literals are in the `Num` class.  IMO, `fromInteger` should have its own class.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Would you kindly provide a link? I've started adding no-constructor datatypes (`Addition` and so on) and a MPTC `Has` just so I can write `sub :: (Has Addition a, Has Negation a) => a -> a -> a`. I'd like to compare approaches!

Comment: @yatima2975 Sorry. I can't find it anymore.

Comment: It is a known design failure. With the addition of one :: a, and zero :: a, the default definitions could still be supplied. One of the most obvious candidates for a Bits instance is Bool!